# ODI Interface execution error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have created a simple ODI interface that will read from a flat file and insert into a Oracle table. However, when i execute the interface, it fails in one of the steps giving the error message : ORA-00936: missing expression

The code generated by this step is :-

```
  /* DETECTION_STRATEGY = NOT_EXISTS */



insert /*+ append */ into ODI_STAGE.I$_CSV_TEST 
  (
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    IND_UPDATE
)
select 
FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    IND_UPDATE
 from (



select   



C1_FIRSTNAME FIRSTNAME,
C2_LASTNAME LASTNAME,

'I' IND_UPDATE


from    ODI_STAGE.C$_0CSV_TEST
where   (1=1)



) S
where NOT EXISTS 
    ( select 1 from ODI_STAGE.CSV_TEST T
    where

         and ((T.FIRSTNAME = S.FIRSTNAME) or (T.FIRSTNAME IS NULL and S.FIRSTNAME IS NULL)) and
        ((T.LASTNAME = S.LASTNAME) or (T.LASTNAME IS NULL and S.LASTNAME IS NULL))
        )
```

Can some one please suggest what is wrong with this query? As I don't see any syntactical issue with it.

Comment: `where and` isn't valid syntax without an intervening expression

Comment: Oh correct!!! How did I miss that out? But any idea how come ODI generated a code like this?

Answer (score 1):

What is syntactically wrong with the query generated by the LKM used is that it inserts the operator AND immediately after the the last where clause. If you copy the code to sql developer or toad and run the query you will definitely get the same error. If you remove the AND after the last where clause you the query will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the interface you're using is not that simple.
I see there's nested SELECT in the FROM clause
Either you're using temporary interface as a source (sub-query) for this interface
OR the IKM (Integration Knowledge Module) used for this is quite fancy.

Usually the implementation of IKMs builds the WHERE condition starting from `WHERE (1=1)`. Thanks to that all conditions defined in the interface can safely be subsequently inserted using `AND (…)` into such template.

Based on the information provided it's difficult to tell what went wrong there. Either make this interface truly simple (no sub-query based derived tables) if that's the case or look deeper at the IKM you're using with that interface.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the IKM and LKM used.
**Try using "IKM Oracle Incremental Update" and "LKM FILE to SQL"**. with this your error should be gone.